# sorting list by util.date field is not properly sorting if day of util.date is single digit

Tags: java, date

below is my pojo class

```
import java.util.Date;
public class SortingDate implements Comparable<SortingDate> {

    private Date date;
    private String type;
    private String motion;
    private Date startDateTime;
    private Date endDateTime;
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getMotion() {
        return motion;
    }
    public void setMotion(String motion) {
        this.motion = motion;
    }
    public Date getStartDateTime() {
        return startDateTime;
    }
    public void setStartDateTime(Date startDateTime) {
        this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
    }
    public Date getEndDateTime() {
        return endDateTime;
    }
    public void setEndDateTime(Date endDateTime) {
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SortingDate o) {
        return getStartDateTime().compareTo(o.getStartDateTime());
    }   
}
```

i am trying to sort by StartDateTime field in ascending order. when i try to put sample date ex:2015-07-01 it is not sorting this instance if my date is double digit it is sorting correctly.

My implementation follows:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class SortingDateImpl {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    List<SortingDate> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
    SortingDate MO1 = addInstance("1-10-15","DAY","AREWR-DEP",formatter.parse("2015-06-10"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO21 = addInstance("1-10-15","DAY","ARERR",formatter.parse("2015-06-13"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO22 = addInstance("1-10-15","Evening","DSAEP",formatter.parse("2015-06-14"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO31 = addInstance("1-10-15","Evening","AASDRR",formatter.parse("2015-06-23"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO32 = addInstance("1-10-15","Night","AADSDRR",formatter.parse("2015-06-15"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO33 = addInstance("1-10-16","DAY","ARASDFR",formatter.parse("2015-06-19"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO34 = addInstance("1-10-16","Evening","DEADSEP",formatter.parse("2015-07-01"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO41 = addInstance("1-10-16","Night","AGHGFDSR",formatter.parse("2015-06-24"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO42 = addInstance("1-10-16","DAY","ARWERR",formatter.parse("2015-06-29"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO43 = addInstance("1-10-16","Evening","DDFGP",formatter.parse("2015-06-23"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO51 = addInstance("1-10-15","DAY","ARRER",formatter.parse("2015-06-11"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO52= addInstance("1-10-15","Evening","ARERR",formatter.parse("2015-06-17"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO53 = addInstance("1-10-15","Night","ARRYTR",formatter.parse("2015-06-30"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    SortingDate MO54 = addInstance("1-10-16","DAY","ARYRRR",formatter.parse("2015-06-26"),formatter.parse("2015-06-11"));
    list.add(MO1);
    list.add(MO21);
    list.add(MO22);
    list.add(MO31);
    list.add(MO32);
    list.add(MO33);
    list.add(MO34);
    list.add(MO41);
    list.add(MO42);
    list.add(MO43);
    list.add(MO51);
    list.add(MO52);
    list.add(MO53);
    list.add(MO54);
    for(SortingDate sortingDate:list){
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(sortingDate.getStartDateTime().toString());
    }

    }catch(ParseException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static SortingDate addInstance(String mDate,String mType,String mPortion,Date startdatetime,Date enddatetime) throws ParseException{
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    SortingDate workUnitBoxInstance = new SortingDate();
    workUnitBoxInstance.setDate(formatter.parse(mDate));
    workUnitBoxInstance.setType("DAY");
    workUnitBoxInstance.setMotion(mPortion);
    workUnitBoxInstance.setStartDateTime(startdatetime);
    workUnitBoxInstance.setEndDateTime(enddatetime);
    return workUnitBoxInstance;

}
}
```

Output:

```
Sat Jan 10 00:06:00 IST 2015
Sat Jan 10 00:06:00 IST 2015
Sun Jan 11 00:06:00 IST 2015
Tue Jan 13 00:06:00 IST 2015
Wed Jan 14 00:06:00 IST 2015
Thu Jan 15 00:06:00 IST 2015
Sat Jan 17 00:06:00 IST 2015
Mon Jan 19 00:06:00 IST 2015
Fri Jan 23 00:06:00 IST 2015
Fri Jan 23 00:06:00 IST 2015
Sat Jan 24 00:06:00 IST 2015
Mon Jan 26 00:06:00 IST 2015
Thu Jan 29 00:06:00 IST 2015
Fri Jan 30 00:06:00 IST 2015
```

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");` ==> `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`... `mm` is for minutes.

Comment: @assylias no, its again same output.not working

Comment: Your parsing pattern of `"yyyy-mm-dd"` does not match your input strings `"1-10-15"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to extract the sort method of the loop !

```
Collections.sort(list);
for(SortingDate sortingDate:list){
    System.out.println(sortingDate.getStartDateTime().toString());
}
```

And comment of @assylias is true !

`mm` is for minutes
`MM` is for month

You should use pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd"` for the formatter

Comment: "Try to extract the sort method of the loop !" worked

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by dams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39832255/642706) is correct.

Also, your parsing pattern of `"yyyy-mm-dd"` does not match your input strings `"1-10-15"`.

You are working too hard here, using the wrong classes.

You are using the troublesome old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

And you are using a date-time class `java.util.Date` to represent a date-only value. The time-of-day `00:00:00` is being set implicitly in your `Date` object, to the UTC time zone. And you use variables named “datetime” that in fact are meant to hold date-only values (confusing and misleading).

Sometimes you use strings that comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard (YYYY-MM-DD) and sometimes you do not. I suggest you stick with the standard format strictly.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern. So you can drop your `formatter` object and all the calls to `formatter.parse`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2015-06-29" );
```

The `LocalDate` class implements `Comparable` and the `compareTo` method.

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).